# Regular expressions: contains at least two 0s but not consecutive 0s

Tags: regex, nlp

Is the solution of this exercise the below regular expression? I found it in the internet but I don't believe that this is correct.

```
(1*011*(0+011*))*
```

According to the theory of Chapter 1 in the book "The handbook of computational linguistics and natural language processing", how could I solve this exercise?

I would like a regular expression that will satisfy the below regular language

```
    L = {010,0101,0110,0101010,01011110,.....}
```

Comment: If you got an exercise you're probably learning regex. Why don't try to learn it then. Check this page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info.

Comment: If you look inside your regexp, you'll see the pattern `0+` which matches at leas one 0, so two consecutive 0's are possible **inside** the regexp, so it shouldn't be valid, at least as how you have asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
^[^0]*[0]{1}([^0]+[0]{1}[^0]*)+$
```

Comment: Now it will force at least two non-consecutive zeros. And will match with more non-consecutive zeros.

Comment: It does match it now.

Comment: Or `^[^0]*0([^0]+0[^0]*)+$` ;)

Comment: I like quantifiers. ;) They make things clearer to me. :)

Comment: Then write it `^[^0]{0,}0([^0]+0[^0]{0,}){1,}$` ;)

Comment: `*`, `+`, `?` are technically quantifiers as well. ;) And the stray `,` doesn't look so good. :P Anyway, this is offtopic.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with:

```
^(?!.*00.*)(?=.*0.*0).*$
```

You can play with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/mY2xD7/5).

Explanation:

- `(?!.*00.*)` the input can't have two consecutive `0`
- `(?=0.*0)` the input have to contains at least two `0`

---

If you don't want to use lookaround use Maria's answer

Comment: I want  to use only the basic operations. (*,|,+) Is it possible?

Comment: 0230 doesn't match.

Comment: This regex still doesn't match all eligible cases. But here is an improvement
`^(?!.*00.*)(?=.*0.*0).*$`

Answer (score 1):

```
(1+01)* 0 (1+) 0 (1+10)*
```

This solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
0[^0]+0
```

Zero `0` followed by a character in the range "not zero" `[^0]` followed by zero `0`.

Comment: What about 01010? Your reg. expression can't recognize it.

Comment: @DimitrisDimitriadis Why wouldn't it? It does.

Comment: @DimitrisDimitriadis If you mean it doesn't match *the whole* string that's true, but why would it?

Comment: The regular language must contain all the strings that satisfy the exercise's rule. {010,0101,0101010,01110 ......}

Comment: It certainly does match it. You can try it in your browser. Open up the dev-console (Ctrl+f12) and paste this:
    /0[^0]+0/.match("01010")

Comment: it matches it partially, but not globally.  Don't use your browser, nor any library from php, java or python to test, as they implement incorrectly the pattern matching algorithm of the equivalent NFA or DFA.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by globally, nor in what sense those implementations should be wrong. I'd like to see a reference to that.

Answer (score 0):

The regexp you post is erroneous, it suffices to note that it has a `0+` subsequence, which should admit a sequence of one or more `0`s.  It can be corrected with this solution:

```
1*011*0(10?)*
```

or with `+` operator

```
1*01+0(10?)*
```

An explanation of it should be:  First skip al the ones that start your expression with the `1*` subpattern, so you get to the first `0`, then skip **at least one** `1`, and all the `1`s following it  (with subpattern `1+`) up to the second `0`, so we have just matched the minimum length string that matches you regular language.  Once here, all the rest is optional, we need to repeat any number of times the pattern `1` with an optional trailing `0` (as in `10?`), or there should be two consecutive `0`s. You can check it in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY9fB9/1), that contains all the possible strings from 1 to 8 characters, and the matching or not of them.

Answer (score 0):

If it's atleast 2 0s, then there's also a possibility of 1 being at the start
So wouldn't that be 1* 0 1* 0 (1+01)*
But if it's acc to the language given (the 2 0s at the beginning and end),
0 (1+01)* 0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
1*01(1|01)*01*
```

I think this would work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Given language contains at least two zeroes but not consecutive zeroes.

The strings accepted by this language are L= {010,0101,0110,0101010,01011110,.....}

The matching regular expression is:

```
1*01*(10+101*)^+
```

Here `+` represents at least a one time occurrence.

DFA for the above language is shown in this link:

[DFA IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO4Xz.jpg)